# Solidity: Error from function transferFrom even after approval [ERC20]

Tags: solidity, erc-20, erc-20-approve

I'm new to Solidity. My contract tries to receive the Chainlink ERC20 token on Rinkeby testnet from a users address.

First transaction: user gives approval. This goes through.

Second transaction: user calls contract function to pull the token. This fails by error "execution reverted".

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.6.0 <0.9.0;

interface IERC20 { 
   function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
   function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
}

contract theContract {
    
    //Chainlink Contract Address on Rinkeby
    IERC20 myToken = IERC20(0x01BE23585060835E02B77ef475b0Cc51aA1e0709);
    
    function askForApproval(uint256 amount) public payable returns (bool) {
        return myToken.approve(address(this), amount);
    }

    function pullToken(uint256 amount) public payable returns (bool) {
        return myToken.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
    }
}
```

I kind of gave up on this. Would be very glad if someone can give me a hint. Thanks

Comment: What does askForApproval

Comment: The user should approve the tokens using directly the original contract and not ur contract

Comment: Hi @Majd TL, what do you mean by original contract?

Comment: the user should call the approve function in 0x01BE23585060835E02B77ef475b0Cc51aA1e0709 directly and not through your contract.